# Extracting data from vector that equals X and counting them

Tags: python

Can someone help me how to do the following operation in Python?

For instance, say I have vector X in R,

```
X = seq(1:50)
```

I want to find where 10 is located and how many there are, if any. What I would in R is,

```
length(which(X==10))
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: just fyi, in R, you could do `sum(X==10)` (`X == 10` is a vector of booleans, and sum coerces them into 0s and 1s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using pandas for R-like operations:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(range(1, 51))
>>> sum(x == 10)
1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a series vector, X with float64 dtype. I know there is a bunch of 3.550 in the data. So, sum(x==3.550) should give me something positive. However, I get a zero. Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: it is likely some rounding issue. you could try: `sum(abs(x - 3.550) < 0.0001)`

Answer (score 1):

The correspondent in python would be

```
>>> X = range(1, 51) #X = seq(1:50)
>>> info = [(idx, value) for idx, value in enumerated(X) if value==10]
>>> print info
(9, 10) #i.e. element in index 9 has value 10
>>> print len(info)
1 #i.e. there is 1 element with value 10 in your original list
```

That way you'll have how many `10` there are, and **where** they are (according to the indexes)

Comment: @Zelazny7 Well-observed.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
X = range(1,50)
print(X.count(10))
#1
```